# WSL - how to connect to VcXserv/Xming when VPN is running in the hosted OS?

Tags: vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, xming, vcxsrv

For work for a vendor, I need to access a few sites via their VPN. Due to the security, however, their VPN blocks basically all other network traffic.

For that, I decided to try the WSL/Linux subsystem. What I really need is just a browser and Cisco Anyconnect.

Setup:
WSL2 running Ubuntu
VcXserv installed and running
Connection tested, I can open Firefox
Cisco Anyconnect installed and tested

Problem: As the connection to VcXserv is effectively via the network, the moment I log in to the VPN, the system loses the connection to the VcXserv running on the hosting Windows. Is there a way to route the VcXserv traffic outside of the VPN, having the ability to connect to the VPN, AND be able to connect to VxServ (effectively open apps)?

Thank you!

For the record, I am running on a relatively low-end business machine, so I don't want to use Virtualbox with a full-fat distro to minimize the resources needed to run that one VPN'd browser window. That is why I didn't go initially with Virtualbox or similar.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to route the VcXserv traffic outside of the VPN, having the ability to connect to the VPN, AND be able to connect to VxServ (effectively open apps)?

Normally it's already routed outside of the VPN. The Cisco VPN client uses a different mechanism to deliberately block all LAN traffic (think of it as a hidden Windows Firewall rule), and I don't think you can easily get rid of it; not even if you disable Windows Firewall.

It is not always *enforced* – open the Cisco AnyConnect settings window (the 'gear' button) and check whether you have this option available – in some cases, you can just disable it yourself.

[image]

Other than that, the only remaining method that I know of is to use a *non-IP* connection. Hyper-V (including WSL2) supports VSOCK connections between the host and guests, and at least the "X410" X server can be configured to [listen for VSOCK connections](https://x410.dev/cookbook/wsl/using-x410-with-wsl2/#vsock).

Finally, don't forget about WSLg which is basically built-in support for running Wayland apps through WSL2 (or even X11 apps, with Xwayland doing the translation). So you *don't need* an X server on Windows at all.

> For the record, I am running on a relatively low-end business machine, so I don't want to use Virtualbox with a full-fat distro

I doubt that would matter. Xorg running inside the VM will use just about the same amount of resources as Xming does outside the VM; probably even less, really.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are facing the same issue, as the rest of us that 'blindly' went ahead and upgraded to WLS2...
I see some (other postings in SO) is diverting to this Cisco AnyConnect, troubleshooter:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect410/administration/guide/b-anyconnect-admin-guide-4-10/troubleshoot-anyconnect.html#Cisco_Task_in_List_GUI.dita_3a9a8101-f034-4e9b-b24a-486ee47b5e9f

locate section: Connectivity Issues with VM-based Subsystems
I just stumbled over it today, trying see if I can workaround this.
Unfortunately, I think the suggested actions need Elevated Rights, and I am not able to retrieve that in my situation.